# How to transport liquid yeast?

Tags: yeast, transport

The home brew shop I go to is about a 45 min drive from my house.

Do I need a cool box or ice pack to get liquid yeast back home and in my fridge?

The guy at the store said that's what I'll need to do but I've read online about people shipping it over multiple days to hot climates and it's been fine.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquid yeast will survive for many days, and probably weeks, outside of being refrigerated.  No need to overthink this.  The yeast will be just fine until you get home.  Cheers.

Comment: And I wouldn't trust your shop owner for much -- sounds a bit mad to me.